# findViewById() returns null for Views in a Dialog

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-resources, android-dialog, findviewbyid

The problem is, no matter where or how I call for this layout's components, they always return null.

```
setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_layout, null))
```

This works fine. It displays the layout inside the `Dialog`, yet, the children are always returned as null by `findViewById(R.id.some_search_layout_children)`.

I've tried cleaning my project multiple times, tried to implement another class for my `Dialog`, called `findViewById()` as a member of my main `Activity`, inside the `initSearch()` method, and inside an anonymous implementation of `OnClickListener` for the `Dialog`, but all with the same result. I've also tried breaking the children out into independent `View`s and programmatically calling them:

```
TextView text = (TextView) findResourceById(R.id.new_independant_textview);
```

But, again, the same result.

This is the relevant code:

```
public class Xyz extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(...) { // some listener will trigger initSearch() }

    private void initSearch() {
        AlertDialog.Builder searchDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        searchDialog.setTitle("Search Photos");
        searchDialog.setMessage("Specify tag and value...");
        // R.layout.search_dialog is my custom layour, it displays fine, it works. 
        searchDialog.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_dialog, null));
        EditText tagText = (EdiText) findViewById(R.id.tagField); // WILL RETURN NULL
        searchDialog.setPositiveButton( ... ) ...
        searchDialog.show();
    }
```

This line:

```
 EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tagField);
```

always returns null, no matter how or where it's called – globally, local `final`, etc. – it just returns null.

Here is the XML of my custom `Dialog` layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/search_dialog"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tagText" 
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="@string/tag" />
    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/tagField"
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/valueText" 
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="@string/value" />
    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/valueField"
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my `R.java` file:

```
public static final class id {
    public static final int action_settings=0x7f0a0011;
    public static final int add_album=0x7f0a0001;
    public static final int add_photo=0x7f0a000d;
    public static final int albums_list=0x7f0a0003;
    public static final int delete_album=0x7f0a000b;
    public static final int exit_finder=0x7f0a000f;
    public static final int new_directory=0x7f0a000e;
    public static final int open_album=0x7f0a000a;
    public static final int photos_grid=0x7f0a0000;
    public static final int rename_album=0x7f0a000c;
    public static final int search_dialog=0x7f0a0004;
    public static final int search_icon=0x7f0a0002;
    public static final int splash_rutgers=0x7f0a0009;
    public static final int tagField=0x7f0a0006; // problematic
    public static final int tagText=0x7f0a0005; / problematic
    public static final int terminate_app=0x7f0a0010;
    public static final int valueField=0x7f0a0008; // problematic
    public static final int valueText=0x7f0a0007; // problematic
}
```

Comment: you wana find view in dialog calling findViewById from another activity ... good luck ...

Comment: Sounds interesting,but I am not fuly understanding why I need a new activity. Then why R.layot.search_dialog returns the right layour yet it's children are null? No consistency there.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Calling `findViewById()` will search for views within your **Activity's** layout and **not** your dialog's view. You need to call `findViewById()` on the specific `View` that you set as your dialog's layout.

Try this

```
private void initSearch() {
    AlertDialog.Builder searchDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    searchDialog.setTitle("Search Photos");
    searchDialog.setMessage("Specify tag and value...");
    // R.layout.search_dialog is my custom layour, it displays fine, it works. 
    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_dialog, null);
    searchDialog.setView(dialogView);
    EditText tagText = (EdiText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.tagField); 
    searchDialog.setPositiveButton( ... ) ...
    AlertDialog myAlert = searchDialog.create(); //returns an AlertDialog from a Builder.
    myAlert.show();
}
```

Notice how I'm inflating the view and storing it in a `View` named `dialogView`. Then, to find your `EditText` named `tagField`, I'm using `dialogView.findViewById(R.id.tagField);`

Comment: Right answer. Thanks guys.

Comment: Saved my day, Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

The `TextView` with id `text123` has  to be declared inside the `Layout` you set with `setContentView`

Comment: Actually, I think `text123` was meant to be an example because OP has `EditText tagText = (EdiText) findViewById(R.id.tagField); // WILL RETURN NULL` in their "main" code section. But this answer did make me chuckle. +1.

Comment: @TronicZomB I read this EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text123); // returns null, ALWAYS

Comment: Yea I know, I at least hope that OP was using that as an example, is I guess what I was trying to say. Since in other parts of the posted code it looks like they are referencing the items properly. But if they are trying to refernce an `EditText`, the one `text123`, that is not within the layout of the dialog then you are completely correct!

Comment: Typo, I edited, it was an example which I forgot to change. Thanks mates.

Comment: No problem, so tagField is the part of your dialog?

Comment: It is. Just as a hint: Even if I call EditText text = findViewById(R.id.tagField) OUTSIDE any dialog thing, it does the same thing, hence I don't believe has nothing to do with the dialog context. What is curious is that the main layour does inflate in the dialog yet its components don't. Thanks for asking.

Comment: @Fer have you tried something like `EditText text = (EditText) getDialog().findViewById()`?

Comment: inside initSearc(), after setTitle and setMessage you can do:

AlertDialog dialog = searchDialog.create();
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.search_dialog);
dialog.findViewById(R.id.tagField);

it should work. It has for me

Comment: Both TronicZomB and blackbelt hit on the nail. Thanks mates for your knowledge. I was missing the context in an actual dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are trying to do `.show()` on a AlertDialog Builder, not the AlertDialog itself.

Try the following code:

```
public class Xyz extends Activity {
public void onCreate(...) { // some listener will trigger initSearch() }

private void initSearch() {
    AlertDialog.Builder searchDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    searchDialog.setTitle("Search Photos");
    searchDialog.setMessage("Specify tag and value...");
    // R.layout.search_dialog is my custom layour, it displays fine, it works. 
    searchDialog.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_dialog, null));
    EditText tagText = (EdiText) findViewById(R.id.tagField); // WILL RETURN NULL
    searchDialog.setPositiveButton( ... ) ...
    AlertDialog myAlert = searchDialog.create(); //returns an AlertDialog from a Builder.
    myAlert.show();
}
```

Comment: Actually, it is possible to call `show()` on a `Builder`, it just creates the `AlertDialog` and shows it. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html

Comment: Good approach though. The solution is to Create a shell Dialog, instantiate it with the Builder, setContentView on the Dialog, setView on the Builder, then findViewById on the dialog instance.

Comment: @Fer oh thanks! I usually use DialogFragments and just return the `builder.create()` and then show it when I need to and thus I hadn't known that `.show()` will create and show it in one line. Though it's good to know.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem while programming a multilingual app.
Eventually I found out that I forgot to update labels in some layout's activity [xml] files.

I had 3 of them per activity:

```
<activity_name>.xml
<activity_name>.xml(land)
<activity_name>.xml(iw)
```

I updated only the first and forgot to update the other as follows:

All three had the a single TextView with the id of:

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/loading_textbox"
    .../>
```

Then I've changed the name of the id of that text view - only in the first file - to:

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/status_textbox"
    .../>
```

And, of-course, in the Activity's Java code (that uses all three...):

```
    TextView tv = findViewByID(R.id.status_textbox);
```

This worked for the regular (English `<activity_name>.xml`) version.

But when I went the the IW language (Hebrew `<activity_name>xml(iw)`) `tv` got null value and I even got some crushes.

When I changed the text view id of the other files to `"@+id/status_textbox"` everything worked like a charm...

So, simply make sure all your IDs are updated and accounted for in all your layouts and languages.

This solved my problem anyway..